# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: mysql

The following stored procedure is throwing me an SQL error. I can't figure out what's causing it.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_results_dailyearnings;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_results_dailyearnings AS
        SELECT emp_id, date_, sum(ifnull(reg_hours,0)) reg_hours, sum(ifnull(ot_hours,0)) ot_hours, SUM(ifnull(allowance,0)) allowance,
                (sum(ifnull(reg_hours,0)) + sum(ifnull(ot_hours,0)) + SUM(ifnull(allowance,0))) gross, SUM(ifnull(LEAV,0)) SIL
        FROM vw_totaldailyearnings
        WHERE date_ between "2018-05-08" and "2018-05-21"
        GROUP BY emp_id, date_
        ORDER BY date_ ASC;

            SELECT CONCAT('
            SELECT emp_id, concat(b.last_name,'','',b.first_name,'','',b.middle_name) name, ',cores_by_dates,', IFNULL(ot_hours,0) ot_hours, IFNULL(allowance,0) allowance,
                    gross, SIL
            FROM tmp_results_dailyearnings a
            inner join tbl_employee b
            on a.emp_id = b.id
            GROUP BY a.emp_id, a.ot_hours, a.allowance, a.gross
            ORDER BY a.emp_id'
            )
            INTO @query
            FROM
            (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN date_=''',actual_date,''' THEN reg_hours END), ''0'') AS "',col_name,'"')) cores_by_dates
            FROM (
            SELECT actual_date, DATE_FORMAT(actual_date,'%a %m/%d') AS col_name
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date_ AS actual_date FROM tmp_results_dailyearnings) AS dates
            ) dates_with_col_names
            ) result;

            drop table if exists tmp_earningsReport;
            SET @createSQL = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_earningsReport AS ', @query);
            PREPARE statement FROM @createSQL;
            EXECUTE statement;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

The error message that I keep on getting is check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near *'ifnull(ot_hours,0) ot_hours, IFNULL(allowance,0) allowance, gross, 0 SIL'* at line 2

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong quote sequence  ..  in you code for string select  you use only single quoto but if you need  wrap the sql code you should use double quote for avoid conflit to inner single quote

```
 SELECT CONCAT("
        SELECT emp_id, concat(b.last_name,'','',b.first_name,'','',b.middle_name) name, ',cores_by_dates,', IFNULL(ot_hours,0) ot_hours, IFNULL(allowance,0) allowance,
                gross, SIL
        FROM tmp_results_dailyearnings a
        inner join tbl_employee b
        on a.emp_id = b.id
        GROUP BY a.emp_id, a.ot_hours, a.allowance, a.gross
        ORDER BY a.emp_id'" 
        )
```

Comment: It now returns a different error: {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 8"}